# What is different between the original LLVM and Android-NDK LLVM?

Tags: android-ndk, llvm

What is different original LLVM with android-ndk's LLVM?
There are some library of LLVM (e.g. libLLVM.so in android-ndk-r9d).

I want to check different this LLVM with original LLVM.
So, can i download LLVM/Clang source code that used in android-ndk?